# Prevent VSCode from re-opening selected file when switching back to Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code 1.23.0, if I click a file in Explorer to open it, then close the editor, the file will remain selected in Explorer.

Then if I switch to another tab, like Extensions, and switch back to Explorer, it will re-open the selected file.

Any way to prevent this?

Comment: oh my god, I was just about to press the button to ask this same question but one last look at suggestions showed this one. This is incredibly annoying behavior for sure. What's interesting is that it doesn't auto-open any files if you already have files open (even if the selected one is not one of those files (i.e. you closed a file preview while in the SourceControl tab)). Also doesn't auto-open if last selected was a folder.

Comment: @coblr I submitted a feature request [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52638) if you want to watch it.